# Creating data-structures for ansible templates

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I'm trying to create a simple config file that enumerates all the (hostname, ip_address) pairs as part of an ansible task.  What I'd really like to do is something like this (using ansible's global datastructures `groups` and `hostvars`):

```
def grouped_hosts():
  ret = {}
  for group in groups:
    ret[group] = {}

    for host in groups[group]:
      ret[group][host] = hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address']

  return json.dumps(ret)
```

Which would emit a data structure similar to:

```
{"webservers":{"web0":"1.2.3.4","web1":"1.2.3.5"},{"caches":{"cache0":"1.2.3.6"}}}
```

However, I don't know how to build and pass this data structure to my jinja2 template.  I really want to be able to create that datastructure and just put `{{ grouped_hosts()|to_nice_json }}` and call it a day.  But how do I write, and where do I put, that `grouped_hosts()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to create with your template, but if you just want to output this as a json structure, you can do it this way :

```
{ 

{% set gdelim = '' %}
{% for group in groups %}
  {{ gdelim }}"{{group}}": {
    {% set hdelim = '' %}
    {% for host in groups[group] %}
    {{ hdelim }}"{{ host }}": "{{hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address']}}"
    {% set hdelim = ',' %}
    {% endfor %}
  }
{% set gdelim = ',' %}
{% endfor %}

}
```

The `gdelim` and `hdelim` are here to set the delimiter when required (note the delimiters prefixing objects).

At first run, the delimiter is empty, and then `","`. Since the objects are prefixed by the delimiter, you don't have trailing comas, and thus the resulting JSON is valid (but a bit ugly).

Comment: Thanks, yes I used a solution like this myself.  It just felt really clunky having to re-implement a json encoder (plus as the structure of my document changes, I have to go in and change this template again and again).  Thanks for the snippet though!